# Error: export 'ɵisStandalone' (imported as 'ɵisStandalone')

Tags: angular

I am getting this error:

```
./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2015/router.mjs:3312:20-33 - Error: export 'ɵisStandalone' (imported as 'ɵisStandalone')
```

Here is `my package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ss",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44494 --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\"",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44494 --ssl --ssl-cert \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem\" --ssl-key \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key\"",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run SS:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.11",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {}
}
```